# SideInputs corrupt the data in DataFlow's Pipeline

Tags: jena, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow pipeline (SDK 2.1.0, Apache Beam 2.2.0) which simply reads RDF (in N-Triples, so it's just text files) from GCS, transforms it somehow and writes it back to GCS, but in a different bucket. In this pipeline I employ side inputs which are three single files (one file per side input) and use them in a ParDo.

To work with RDF in Java I use Apache Jena, so each file is read into an instance of Model class. Since Dataflow doesn't have Coder for it, I developed it myself (`RDFModelCoder`, see below). It works fine in number of other pipelines I created.

The **problem** with this particular pipeline is when I add the side inputs, the execution fails with an exception indicating a corruption of the data, i.e. some garbage is added. Once I remove the side inputs, the pipeline finishes execution successfully.

The exception (it's thrown from `RDFModelCoder`, see below):

```
Caused by: org.apache.jena.atlas.RuntimeIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.IO.exception(IO.java:233)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.CharStreamBuffered$SourceReader.fill(CharStreamBuffered.java:77)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.CharStreamBuffered.fillArray(CharStreamBuffered.java:154)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.CharStreamBuffered.advance(CharStreamBuffered.java:137)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.PeekReader.advanceAndSet(PeekReader.java:235)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.PeekReader.init(PeekReader.java:229)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.PeekReader.peekChar(PeekReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.io.PeekReader.makeUTF8(PeekReader.java:92)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.tokens.TokenizerFactory.makeTokenizerUTF8(TokenizerFactory.java:48)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.RiotParsers.createParser(RiotParsers.java:57)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:198)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.read(RDFParser.java:298)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parseNotUri(RDFParser.java:288)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:237)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserBuilder.parse(RDFParserBuilder.java:417)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parseFromInputStream(RDFDataMgr.java:870)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:268)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:254)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:69)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:305)
```

And here you can see the garbage (at the end):

```
<http://example.com/typeofrepresentative/08> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> . ������** �����I��.�������������u�������
```

The pipeline:

```
val one = p.apply(TextIO.read().from(config.getString("source.one")))
           .apply(Combine.globally(SingleValue()))
           .apply(ParDo.of(ConvertToRDFModel(RDFLanguages.NTRIPLES)))

val two = p.apply(TextIO.read().from(config.getString("source.two")))
           .apply(Combine.globally(SingleValue()))
           .apply(ParDo.of(ConvertToRDFModel(RDFLanguages.NTRIPLES)))

val three = p.apply(TextIO.read().from(config.getString("source.three")))
             .apply(Combine.globally(SingleValue()))
             .apply(ParDo.of(ConvertToRDFModel(RDFLanguages.NTRIPLES)))

val sideInput = PCollectionList.of(one).and(two).and(three)
                .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
                .apply(View.asList())

p.apply(RDFIO.Read
                  .from(options.getSource())
                  .withSuffix(RDFLanguages.strLangNTriples))
 .apply(ParDo.of(SparqlConstructETL(config, sideInput))
                        .withSideInputs(sideInput))
 .apply(RDFIO.Write
                  .to(options.getDestination())
                  .withSuffix(RDFLanguages.NTRIPLES))
```

And just to provide the whole picture here are implementations of `SingleValue` and `ConvertToRDFModel` ParDos:

```
class SingleValue : SerializableFunction<Iterable<String>, String> {
    override fun apply(input: Iterable<String>?): String {
        if (input != null) {
            return input.joinToString(separator = " ")
        }
        return ""
    }
}

class ConvertToRDFModel(outputLang: Lang) : DoFn<String, Model>() {
    private val lang: String = outputLang.name

    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(c: ProcessContext?) {
        if (c != null) {
            val model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
            model.read(StringReader(c.element()), null, lang)
            c.output(model)
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of `RDFModelCoder`:

```
class RDFModelCoder(private val decodeLang: String = RDFLanguages.strLangNTriples,
                    private val encodeLang: String = RDFLanguages.strLangNTriples)
    : AtomicCoder<Model>() {

    private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RDFModelCoder::class.java)

    override fun decode(inStream: InputStream): Model {
        val bytes = StreamUtils.getBytes(inStream)
        val model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()

        model.read(ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), null, decodeLang) // the exception is thrown from here

        return model
    }

    override fun encode(value: Model, outStream: OutputStream?) {
        value.write(outStream, encodeLang, null)
    }

}
```

I checked the side input files multiple times, they're fine, they have UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: This not a Jena issue.  The input is not valid UTF-8.  PeekReader slurps quite large buffer (128K bytes) to improve byte to character conversion. Hence MalformedInputException.  The length = 1 means it is an illegal one byte UTF-8 sequence in that block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the error is in the implementation of `RDFModelCoder`. When implementing `encode`/`decode` one has to remember that the provided `InputStream` and `OutputStream` are not exclusively owned by the current instance being encoded/decoded. E.g. there might be more data in the `InputStream` after the encoded form of your current `Model`. When using `StreamUtils.getBytes(inStream)` you are grabbing both data of the current encoded `Model` and anything else that was in the stream.

Generally when writing a new `Coder` it's a good idea to only combine existing `Coder`'s rather than hand-parsing the stream: that is less error-prone. I would suggest to convert the model to/from `byte[]` and use `ByteArrayCoder.of()` to encode/decode it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't (de)serialize using Java Serialization mechanism or Kryo (in example), because the Model is not easily serializable, so I have to write it to a text format and read it back. I tried to use Kryo for this task, but without any success.

Comment: How can I make sure that I don't read more than needed from the input stream?

Comment: Looks like it helped, I'm still testing, but first tests passed! I looked at StringUtf8Coder and found that they call `VarInt.encode` and `VarInt.decode` to write/read the length of a chunk in the stream. I don't know why I didn't find it earlier, maybe because the documentation is not so clear about that...

Answer (score 1):

Apache Jena provides the [Elephas IO](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/hadoop/io.html) modules which have Hadoop IO support, since Beam supports [Hadoop InputFormat IO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hadoop/inputformat/HadoopInputFormatIO.html) you should be able to use that to read in your NTriples file.

This will likely be far more efficient since the [NTriples support in Elephas](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/elephas/elephas-io/org/apache/jena/hadoop/rdf/io/input/ntriples/NTriplesInputFormat.html) is able to parallelise the IO and avoid caching the entire model into memory (in fact it won't use `Model` at all):

```
Configuration myHadoopConfiguration = new Configuration(false);

// Set Hadoop InputFormat, key and value class in configuration
myHadoopConfiguration.setClass("mapreduce.job.inputformat.class",
                               NTriplesInputFormat.class, InputFormat.class);
myHadoopConfiguration.setClass("key.class", LongWritable.class, Object.class);
myHadoopConfiguration.setClass("value.class", TripleWritable.class, Object.class);
// Set any other Hadoop config you might need

// Read data only with Hadoop configuration.
p.apply("read",
         HadoopInputFormatIO.<LongWritable, TripleWritable>read()
        .withConfiguration(myHadoopConfiguration);
```

Of course this may require you to refactor your overall pipeline somewhat.